# Confused about running Scrapy from within a Python script

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Following [document](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script), I can run scrapy from a Python script, but I can't get the scrapy result.

This is my spider:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "douban" 
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.example.com/group/xxx/discussion"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        rows = hxs.select("//table[@class='olt']/tr/td[@class='title']/a")
        items = []
        # print sites
        for row in rows:
            item = DmozItem()
            item["title"] = row.select('text()').extract()[0]
            item["link"] = row.select('@href').extract()[0]
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

Notice the last line, I try to use the returned parse result, if I run:

```
 scrapy crawl douban
```

the terminal could print the return result

But I can't get the return result from the Python script.  Here is my Python script:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from scrapy import log, signals
from spiders.dmoz_spider import DmozSpider
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

def stop_reactor():
    reactor.stop()
dispatcher.connect(stop_reactor, signal=signals.spider_closed)
spider = DmozSpider(domain='www.douban.com')
crawler = Crawler(Settings())
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()
log.start()
log.msg("------------>Running reactor")
result = reactor.run()
print result
log.msg("------------>Running stoped")
```

I try to get the result at the `reactor.run()`, but it return nothing,

How can I get the result?

Comment: where do you put the script please? in the scrapy project, or in the spider folder, or what?

Comment: Cross-referencing [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27744766/771848) - should give you a detailed overview on how to run Scrapy from a script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Terminal prints the result because the default log level is set to `DEBUG`.

When you are running your spider from the script and call `log.start()`, the default log level is set to `INFO`.

Just replace:

```
log.start()
```

with

```
log.start(loglevel=log.DEBUG)
```

UPD:

To get the result as string, you can log everything to a file and then read from it, e.g.:

```
log.start(logfile="results.log", loglevel=log.DEBUG, crawler=crawler, logstdout=False)

reactor.run()

with open("results.log", "r") as f:
    result = f.read()
print result
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you,this solve one of the problems, but how can I in the script the get the return result in spider? what's wrong with `result = reactor.run()`

Comment: You are welcome. I've updated the answer - added an option how to get the results as string.

Comment: That permit show the output but instead of collect the data from there I think the proper way to do this is write or use pipelines.

Comment: please where should I put the script? i want to run the spider from the script, i can do that as the question says. but i don't know where to put that script. should I put it directly in the project folder? or in the spider folder? or what. thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

I found your question while asking myself the same thing, namely: "How can I get the result?". Since this wasn't answered here I endeavoured to find the answer myself and now that I have I can share it:

```python
items = []
def add_item(item):
    items.append(item)
dispatcher.connect(add_item, signal=signals.item_passed)
```

Or for scrapy 0.22 (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script) replace the last line of my solution by:

```python
crawler.signals.connect(add_item, signals.item_passed)
```

My solution is freely adapted from http://www.tryolabs.com/Blog/2011/09/27/calling-scrapy-python-script/.

Comment: This works perfectly for me however, since version 1.1 of Scrapy, it gives me a deprecation warning on the line "from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher" which is ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Importing from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch is deprecated and will no longer be supported in future Scrapy versions. If you just want to connect signals use the from_crawler class method, otherwise import pydispatch directly if needed. See: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1762
  from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i placed the script file at scrapy project level e.g. if scrapyproject/scrapyproject/spiders then i placed it at scrapyproject/myscript.py