# Get scrapy result inside a Django view

Tags: django, scrapy

I'm scrapping a page successfully that returns me an unique item. I don't want neither to save the scrapped item in the database nor to a file. I need to get it inside a Django view.

My view is as follows:

```
def start_crawl(process_number, court):
    """
    Starts the crawler.

        Args:
            process_number (str): Process number to be found.
            court (str): Court of the process.
    """
    runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())
    results = list()

    def crawler_results(sender, parse_result, **kwargs):
        results.append(parse_result)

    dispatcher.connect(crawler_results, signal=signals.item_passed)
    process_info = runner.crawl(MySpider, process_number=process_number, court=court)

    return results
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564305/confused-about-running-scrapy-from-within-a-python-script/23892650#23892650) solution but results list is always empty.

I read something as creating a custom middleware and getting the results at the process_spider_output method.

How can I get the desired result?

Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes you need to do an addtional step to reach your goal. I think it's easier to divide and conquer. Use scrapy to store data into a database. Use django to extract the data out of the database and show it in a view.

Comment: @ThomasStrub The problem here is that it'll be difficult to determine when the data is already in the database after the spider finish and when I get an error scrapping.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to implement something like that in one of my projects. It is a mini-project and I was looking for a quick solution. You'll might need modify it or support multi-threading etc in case you put it in production environment.

## Overview

I created an `ItemPipeline` that just add the items into a `InMemoryItemStore` helper. Then, in my `__main__` code I wait for the crawler to finish, and pop all the items out of the `InMemoryItemStore`. Then I can manipulate the items as I wish.

## Code

### items_store.py

Hacky in-memory store. It is not very elegant but it got the job done for me. Modify and improve if you wish. I've implemented that as a simple class object so I can simply import it anywhere in the project and use it without passing its instance around.

```
class InMemoryItemStore(object):
    __ITEM_STORE = None

    @classmethod
    def pop_items(cls):
        items = cls.__ITEM_STORE or []
        cls.__ITEM_STORE = None
        return items

    @classmethod
    def add_item(cls, item):
        if not cls.__ITEM_STORE:
            cls.__ITEM_STORE = []
        cls.__ITEM_STORE.append(item)
```

### pipelines.py

This pipleline will store the objects in the in-memory store from the snippet above. All items are simply returned to keep the regular pipeline flow intact. If you don't want to pass some items down the to the other pipelines simply change `process_item` to not return all items.

```
from <your-project>.items_store import InMemoryItemStore


class StoreInMemoryPipeline(object):
    """Add items to the in-memory item store."""
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        InMemoryItemStore.add_item(item)
        return item
```

### settings.py

Now add the `StoreInMemoryPipeline` in the scraper settings. If you change the `process_item` method above, make sure you set the proper priority here (changing the 100 down here).

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   ...
   '<your-project-name>.pipelines.StoreInMemoryPipeline': 100,
   ...
}
```

### main.py

This is where I tie all these things together. I clean the in-memory store, run the crawler, and fetch all the items.

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

from <your-project>.items_store import InMemoryItemStore
from <your-project>.spiders.your_spider import YourSpider

def get_crawler_items(**kwargs):
    InMemoryItemStore.pop_items()

    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    process.crawl(YourSpider, **kwargs)
    process.start()  # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
    process.stop()
    return InMemoryItemStore.pop_items()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    items = get_crawler_items()
```

Comment: Thanks @Almong Cohen! I got an error of signals out of ain threads and ended up getting the desired result with scrapyrt

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to collect all data in a "special" object. 
Store the data in a separate pipeline like https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#duplicates-filter and in close_spider (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html?highlight=close_spider#close_spider) you open your django object.

Comment: Thanks. I visited the links you passed but I couldn't figure out how to avoid saving the collected items in the database

Comment: Store them in a python object and pass them in close_spider to the django view